# Disabled fields are enabled after struts validations

Tags: javascript, struts

I am using java script and struts for validating the forms.

I have 'date' field and a checkbox. The 'date' field is disabled when the checkbox is checked

The issue is, after struts validation my disabled fields are enabled again and the validation error message still appears

```
`<tr class="table_row_odd">
    <td><label class="mandatory">*</label>Date (DD/MM/YYYY) : </td>
    <td>
        <html:text property="day" size="2" maxlength="2" styleClass="form_field" />&nbsp;/&nbsp;
        <html:text property="month" size="2" maxlength="2" styleClass="form_field" />&nbsp;/&nbsp;
        <html:text property="year" size="4" maxlength="4" styleClass="form_field" />
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr class="table_row_odd">
    <td> </td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <html:checkbox property="dateUnknown" value="Y" onclick="javascript:check()" ></html:checkbox>
        Please check if date unknown
    </td>
</tr>
```

---

```
function check()
 {
 if(window.document.getElementById("dateUnknown").checked==true)
 {  window.document.getElementById("day").disabled= true;
    window.document.getElementById("month").disabled= true;
    window.document.getElementById("year").disabled= true;
} }
```

---

```
<form name="/create">
<field property="date"   
            depends="validateDateRequired">
            <arg0 key="errors.required.date" />
            <var>
                <var-name>dayfield</var-name>
                <var-value>day</var-value>
            </var>
            <var>
                <var-name>monthfield</var-name>
                <var-value>month</var-value>
            </var>
            <var>
                <var-name>yearfield</var-name>
                <var-value>year</var-value>
            </var>
        </field>
     </form>
```

---

```
public static boolean validateDaterequired(Object bean, ValidatorAction va, 
        Field field, ActionMessages errors, Validator validator, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    boolean returnValue = true;

    try
    {
        String dayStr = field.getVarValue("day");
        String monthStr = field.getVarValue("month");
        String yearStr = field.getVarValue("year");


        String dayStrValue = (dayStr!=null)?trim((String)PropertyUtils.getProperty(bean, dayStr)):"";
        String monthStrValue = (monthStr!=null)?trim((String)PropertyUtils.getProperty(bean, monthStr)):"";
        String yearStrValue = (yearStr!=null)?trim((String)PropertyUtils.getProperty(bean, yearStr)):"";

        String dt = dayStrValue + monthStrValue + yearStrValue;

        if(trim(dt).length() == 0)
        {

            returnValue = false;
        }

        if(!returnValue) 
        {
            errors.add(field.getKey(), Resources.getActionMessage(request, va, field));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        returnValue = false;
        log.error(e,e);
        errors.add(field.getKey(), Resources.getActionMessage(request, va, field));
    }

    return returnValue;
```

### }

UPDATE:
As I mentioned in the comment below. I tried to call the javascript function in on the windows.onload() as below and the fields are disabled as per the condition. But still the validation error appears. By right the disabled fields validation should be ignored. How to do that in struts validation.xml? any suggestion please.

```
   window.onload=function(){
   check();
    }
```

Comment: when and where is the validateDaterequired java function called from the web page?

Comment: @GraveyardQueen its called from the validation.xml. i have edited and added my validation.xml file also. Please help

Comment: no my question was when the html form gets submitted is the java validation function called?

Comment: @GraveyardQueen yes

Comment: @GraveyardQueen I found that the page is loaded each time after the validation check, so i even tried to use windows.onload to call the javascript function check() each time when the page loads. but still its no use. the text box is enabled again ! any suggestion will help me a lot. Thanks

Comment: so when you put the check() in window.onload did the date fields get disabled?

Comment: @GraveyardQueen yes.